# Finding the similarity dimension of a variation of the Cantor Set.

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, cantor-set

If we take the Cantor set and instead of removing the interval $[1/3, 2/3]$, we remove the open interval $[x,1-x]$, with $0<x<1/2$, will the similarity dimension change? What I think is that we again get scaling factor $3$ and we get two copies of the lines, but rescaled. So the similarity dimension is $\log(2)/\log(3) = 0.63$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the similarity dimension will be different. The generalized Cantor set consists of two copies of itself, scaled by the factor of $x$. So, its dimension (similarity, Hausdorff, box/Minkowski, packing...) is $\log 2/\log(1/x)$.